Why SQLAlchemy ORM faster than oreignal Postgresql?
I built a postgresql on my win11 laptop, ran a select with pgadmin 4 and SQLAlchemy with VSCode. The SQL statements are the same. However, SQLAlchemy is faster than oreign SQL. I just want to know why?
I've tried run both ORM and SQL on cmd, the result still the same.
The SQL statement I used was the stmt ORM generated.
Here are the orm code I used
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, MetaData, Column, func
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import select
import time

db_url = "postgresql://postgres:Bmpsst521@localhost:5432/Teacher_salary"
engine = create_engine(db_url)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

Base = declarative_base()

meta_obj = MetaData()

log_problem = Table(
    "log_problem",
    meta_obj,
    Column("timestamp_tw"),
    Column("uuid"),
    Column("ucid"),
    Column("upid"),
    Column("problem_number"),
    Column("exercise_problem_repeat_session"),
    Column("is_correct"),
    Column("total_sec_taken"),
    Column("total_attempt_cnt"),
    Column("used_hint_cnt"),
    Column("is_hint_used"),
    Column("is_downgrade"),
    Column("is_upgrade"),
    Column("level"),
    Column("id")
)

info_userdata = Table(
    "info_userdata",
    meta_obj,
    Column("uuid"),
    Column("gender"),
    Column("points"),
    Column("badges_cnt"),
    Column("first_login_date_tw"),
    Column("user_grade"),
    Column("user_city"),
    Column("has_teacher_cnt"),
    Column("is_self_coach"),
    Column("has_student_cnt"),
    Column("belongs_to_class_cnt"),
    Column("has_class_cnt"),
    Column("id")
)

Following is how SQLAlchemy generated and the how I use, count time.
stmt = select(
    info_userdata.c.user_grade,
    func.count()
).select_from(log_problem).join(
    info_userdata, log_problem.c.uuid==info_userdata.c.uuid
).group_by(info_userdata.c.user_grade)

print(stmt)

start = time.time()

with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(stmt)
    conn.commit()
end = time.time()

for row in result:
    print(row)

print(end - start) # 3.106472969055176 (in second)

And here is the SQL statement.
SELECT info_userdata.user_grade, count(*) AS count_1 
FROM log_problem 
JOIN info_userdata 
ON log_problem.uuid = info_userdata.uuid 
GROUP BY info_userdata.user_grade;
--3582.067 ms (00:03.582) (using  \timing ON)

Add Query Plan
Teacher_salary=# EXPLAIN SELECT info_userdata.user_grade, count(*) AS count_1 FROM log_problem JOIN info_userdata ON log_problem.uuid = info_userdata.uuid GROUP BY info_userdata.user_grade;
                                                    QUERY PLAN

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=661356.65..661359.69 rows=12 width=12)
   Group Key: info_userdata.user_grade
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=661356.65..661359.45 rows=24 width=12)
         Workers Planned: 2
         ->  Sort  (cost=660356.62..660356.65 rows=12 width=12)
               Sort Key: info_userdata.user_grade
               ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=660356.29..660356.41 rows=12 width=12)
                     Group Key: info_userdata.user_grade
                     ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=2226.98..623588.15 rows=7353627 width=4)
                           Hash Cond: ((log_problem.uuid)::text = (info_userdata.uuid)::text)
                           ->  Parallel Seq Scan on log_problem  (cost=0.00..550528.27 rows=7353627 width=45)
                           ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=1691.99..1691.99 rows=42799 width=49)
                                 ->  Parallel Seq Scan on info_userdata  (cost=0.00..1691.99 rows=42799 width=49)
(13 筆資料)


時間: 7.960 ms

Add result from EXPLAIN(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)
Teacher_salary=# EXPLAIN(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) SELECT info_userdata.user_grade, count(*) AS count_1 FROM log_problem JOIN info_userdata ON log_problem.uuid = info_userdata.uuid GROUP BY info_userdata.user_grade;
                                                                               QUERY PLAN

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=661356.65..661359.69 rows=12 width=12) (actual time=4309.362..4313.947 rows=12 loops=1)
   Output: info_userdata.user_grade, count(*)
   Group Key: info_userdata.user_grade
   Buffers: shared hit=3776 read=474528
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=661356.65..661359.45 rows=24 width=12) (actual time=4309.357..4313.937 rows=36 loops=1)
         Output: info_userdata.user_grade, (PARTIAL count(*))
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         Buffers: shared hit=3776 read=474528
         ->  Sort  (cost=660356.62..660356.65 rows=12 width=12) (actual time=4273.242..4273.244 rows=12 loops=3)
               Output: info_userdata.user_grade, (PARTIAL count(*))
               Sort Key: info_userdata.user_grade
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
               Buffers: shared hit=3776 read=474528
               Worker 0:  actual time=4255.885..4255.887 rows=12 loops=1
                 Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                 Buffers: shared hit=1014 read=171520
               Worker 1:  actual time=4255.106..4255.108 rows=12 loops=1
                 Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                 Buffers: shared hit=638 read=167504
               ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=660356.29..660356.41 rows=12 width=12) (actual time=4273.223..4273.226 rows=12 loops=3)
                     Output: info_userdata.user_grade, PARTIAL count(*)
                     Group Key: info_userdata.user_grade
                     Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 24kB
                     Buffers: shared hit=3762 read=474528
                     Worker 0:  actual time=4255.863..4255.865 rows=12 loops=1
                       Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 24kB
                       Buffers: shared hit=1007 read=171520
                     Worker 1:  actual time=4255.083..4255.087 rows=12 loops=1
                       Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 24kB
                       Buffers: shared hit=631 read=167504
                     ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=2226.98..623588.15 rows=7353627 width=4) (actual time=11.651..3448.484 rows=5405770 loops=3)
                           Output: info_userdata.user_grade
                           Hash Cond: ((log_problem.uuid)::text = (info_userdata.uuid)::text)
                           Buffers: shared hit=3762 read=474528
                           Worker 0:  actual time=0.374..3460.534 rows=5865102 loops=1
                             Buffers: shared hit=1007 read=171520
                           Worker 1:  actual time=0.455..3415.051 rows=5715842 loops=1
                             Buffers: shared hit=631 read=167504
                           ->  Parallel Seq Scan on public.log_problem  (cost=0.00..550528.27 rows=7353627 width=45) (actual time=0.254..1568.013 rows=5405770 loops=3)
                                 Output: log_problem.uuid
                                 Buffers: shared hit=2464 read=474528
                                 Worker 0:  actual time=0.294..1579.935 rows=5865102 loops=1
                                   Buffers: shared hit=990 read=171520
                                 Worker 1:  actual time=0.389..1556.809 rows=5715842 loops=1
                                   Buffers: shared hit=614 read=167504
                           ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=1691.99..1691.99 rows=42799 width=49) (actual time=11.122..11.123 rows=24253 loops=3)
                                 Output: info_userdata.user_grade, info_userdata.uuid
                                 Buckets: 131072  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 7296kB
                                 Buffers: shared hit=1264
                                 Worker 0:  actual time=0.014..0.015 rows=0 loops=1
                                 Worker 1:  actual time=0.013..0.014 rows=0 loops=1
                                 ->  Parallel Seq Scan on public.info_userdata  (cost=0.00..1691.99 rows=42799 width=49) (actual time=0.007..11.095 rows=72758 loops=1)
                                       Output: info_userdata.user_grade, info_userdata.uuid
                                       Buffers: shared hit=1264
 Planning Time: 0.340 ms
 Execution Time: 4314.031 ms
(57 筆資料)


At least share the query plans, using explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for your SQL statements. All in plain text, not images

Sorry I add the query in text.

Most likely something went wrong, but I don't see any query plan.


How are you measuring the time in the SQLAlchemy code? 2) There is no time unit for the SQLAlchemy result. Could it be that is in seconds whereas the psql results are in milliseconds? 3) DO NOT use images for textual data, copy and paste as text into the question text.


I add query plan(I just know there's something called query plan sorry

@AdrianKlaver 1) I import time using time.time(). 2) It's in second. 3) I've done.


Per @FrankHeikens comment use explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings).  2) You got rid of the image which is good, now you need to add the time values that where in it to your question as text. Include how you did the timing in psql.


From what I remember of the values in the images the times for SQLAlchemy and psql runs where both in 3.xx secs range and about 0.2- 0.3 sec different. I'm going to say the difference was the time to write to the display in the psql case. Add a result.all() to the SQLAlchemy code and see what happens to the time

The statement used in PSQL is what SQLAlchemy generated, should both have the same query plan? I just look for EXPLAIN in SQLAlchemy doc, only find "you use the EXPLAIN ANALYZE... tool from PostgreSQL to......"

You now posted the result from EXPLAIN, but that's only a plan. We need the result from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) because that gives you all the details about the plan and the execution of the plan.

The result from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) is added.
